# C++/Cli : Could not load file or assembly X or one of its dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

Tags: boost, c++-cli, boost-thread

I have a C++ project, a C++\Cli project and a c# win forms project.
When i access the cli project from win forms project, i can access and use cli project functions. But when i include my cpp project headers into cli project, i get this run time error from my c# project when i access the cli project.

```
  CliWrapper.Func meta = new CliWrapper.Func();
```

This is the error i have taken :

BadImageFormatException : Could not load file or assembly X or one of its dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

I realized that `#include <boost/thread.hpp>` causes the problem

Comment: In your Winforms project: Project + Properties, Compile tab, change Platform target to x86.  Or build a 64-bit version of the C++/CLI assembly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution :

http://marc.info/?l=boost-users&m=123425857320026

> In Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor
>   Definitions add BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK in order to force the usage of the
>   DLLs. In addition copy the necessary DLLs to the directory where the
>   executable resides. E.g. copy boost_thread-vc90-mt-gd-1_XX.dll to
>   MyApp/bin/Debug.

Answer (score 3):

It is very likely that your C++ project is compiled as Win32 and your C# project is either AnyCPU being ran on a 64-bit machine or, simply, an x64 assembly.

Configure your C# and C++/CLI project to target x86 architecture.